# Can SVG elements be tagged for later retrieval?

Tags: javascript, svg

I have many dynamically generated SVGs inside my HTML document. They contain (among other elements) some `<text>` elements, sort of like this:

```
<svg>
    // bunch of other elements
    <text x="50" y="25" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central" class="myclass">info 1</text>
    <text x="50" y="75" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central" class="myclass">info 2</text>
    // more other elements
</svg>
```

Is there anything like an `id` or `name` attribute that I can use for these two pieces of text, so that I can dynamically change them later? `id` is supposed to be unique in the whole document, and I have many of these SVGs. `name` appears to mean something different in SVG (as opposed to HTML forms), and in any case might be deprecated. I'm hesitant to use `class`, since this really isn't about styling and I don't want weird conflicts with other styles that might be present in the document. (I don't have control over the document my code is used in, or its stylesheets.) I also don't want to have to search the whole document for the element I'm looking for, since I'll already have a pointer to its parent. Ideally, I'd do something like this:

```
mySVG.getChildByType("type1").innerHTML = "here's new text";
```

(With the caveat that every similar SVG has one of these `"type1`"` children, that can be grabbed and messed with.)

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you assign new ```id``` for every svg text element when you dynamically create them then as you said change their ```innerHTML```? Have you tried it?

Comment: Sure, but `id`s are supposed to be unique in the entire document. And in any case, it's not clear how I'd grab the element later, if its `id` isn't known.

Comment: either way you are going to have to loop through the svg elements text value to check if that is the text you are looking for then if it is, get the id you assigned it then use the ```.innerHTML``` method to change the text value. If I'm not miss understanding your question this should be easy.

Comment: `id`s need to be unique. If I give one SVG a child with elements with `id`s of `type1` and `type2`, I'm now forbidden from using `type1` and `type2` ever again. So if I want to grab a pointer to one of these `<text>` objects using its `id`, which `id` do I use?

Comment: yeah so when you dynamically create a new svg and assign it a new id you first have to check what the last id you assigned was. Lets say you currently have 1 svg with 2 text elements with first one id ```type1``` and second ```type2```. Now when you create a new svg you are first going to check what the last id you assigned was in this case it's id ```type2``` now split that id and get the number which in this case is ```2``` then add 1 to it and assign it to the newly created svg text element's id this way you dont end with with the same id in different text elements.

Comment: That seems very awkward. Say there are 100 SVGs, and I want to grab the `type1` from SVG #57. This would mean reproducing the calculation to figure out its `id`. It also leads to possible issues with asynchronous code, since you'd need a static variable somewhere to hold the last `id` assigned. It's not a preferred solution.

Comment: what do you mean by "This would mean reproducing the calculation to figure out its id" Its all automated plus how does it created an issue with asynchronous code?

Comment: Oh do you mean you have to run the loop again to find its id after getting its svg number when you said reproducing the calculation if so you are not going to do that there is a thing called ```this``` take a look at it you can use that then use method ```.children``` to get the id without rerunning the loop. Which its so easy and efficient.

Comment: But which child do you grab? I was hoping that there was a way to tag a particular child as the one I want. At this point, I just don't think there is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you think `id` is unusable.  You say you are dynamically generating the SVGs. I presume that means at run-time.  So just generate an `id` at the same time.  Prefix it, if you need to, so that you can be sure it is going to be unique.

```
textElement.setAttribute("id", "my-prefix-" + nextTextElemIndex);
```

There's also nothing stopping you from adding your own custom attribute.  Then style the elements using [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

```css
circle[foo="middle"] {
  fill: green;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="red" foo="left"/>
  <circle cx="150" cy="50" r="50" fill="red" foo="middle"/>
  <circle cx="250" cy="50" r="50" fill="red" foo="right"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks--this might be the solution I end up using. But it does mean that you need to know the prefix used in a specific SVG before doing the search, which is a little annoying.

Comment: I updated my answer with an alternative suggestion.

Comment: id's unusable because it has to be unique. But I didn't know about attribute selectors--that could really help.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly clear what you want; it sounds like you want a way to get the text elements inside of a specific SVG?

In that case, use something like the following:

```
document.querySelectorAll("svg > text")[0].textContent = "I am the new string";
```

Now querySelectorAll() just uses CSS selectors, so you can replace svg in there with a .class, #id, or just use whatever CSS selector you want.

Comment: But the issue is that `id`s are supposed to be unique. I might be forced to use `class` and to mess with CSS, but I was hoping to stay away from that because I don't have control over the document, and I want to minimize class conflicts. (And in any case, the two pieces of text are styled identically.)

Comment: @AdamSmith So what's the issue then? If you wanted to grab every text element from every SVG you could use the above code. If you only want to get the text elements from one of them use document.querySelectorAll("#id-of-svg > text"). Both retrieve arrays containing all the selected elements.

Comment: I'm trying to retrieve a single subelement from a single `<svg>`. It's a `<text>`, but it's not the only `<text>`. I don't know its index. I'd use its `id`, but that's supposed to be unique, and is therefore unusable. What's the best way to mark it when I create the SVG, so I know it's the one I'm looking for? (Preferably in a way that precludes doing a search through the entire document structure.)

Answer (score 1):

You could use rather verbose class names to avoid accidentally overridden  styles inherited from a global css.
E.g a BEM-like naming scheme as commonly used in scripts/libs like image sliders, media players, map helpers.

If your svg text elements are dynamically compiled you might run a function adding index based IDs/class properties:

```js
const parentSvgs = document.querySelectorAll('.mySvg');
setAutoIds(parentSvgs);

function setAutoIds(parents) {
  parents.forEach(function(parent, p) {
    let parentIdentifier = 'mySvg__parent--' + p;
    parent.id = parentIdentifier;
    parent.classList.add(parentIdentifier);
    let children = parent.querySelectorAll('.mySvg__text');
    children.forEach(function(child, c) {
      let childIdentifier = `mySvg__text--${p}-${c}`;
      child.id = childIdentifier;
      child.classList.add(childIdentifier);
      child.classList.add(`mySvg__text--${c}`);
    })
  })
}

//auto content example
setIndexedContent(parentSvgs);

function setIndexedContent(parents) {
  parents.forEach(function(parent, p) {
    let children = parent.querySelectorAll('.mySvg__text');
    children.forEach(function(child, c) {
      child.textContent = `svg nr.${p+1} info nr.${c+1}`;
    });
  });
}

// single text element selected by ID or class
document.getElementById('mySvg__text--1-3').textContent = 'unique text by ID';
document.getElementById('mySvg__text--1-2').textContent = 'unique text by Class';
```

```css
.mySvg {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20vw;
  border: 1px dotted #ccc;
}

.mySvg__text {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.mySvg__text--0 {
  fill: orange
}

.mySvg__text--1 {
  fill: green
}

.mySvg__text--2 {
  fill: red
}
```

```html
<svg class="mySvg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <text x="50" y="25" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central" class="mySvg__text">info</text>
    <text x="50" y="50" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central" class="mySvg__text">info</text>
      <text x="50" y="75" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central" class="mySvg__text">info</text>
</svg>

<svg class="mySvg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <text x="50" y="10" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central" class="mySvg__text">info</text>
    <text x="50" y="20" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central" class="mySvg__text">info</text>
    <text x="50" y="30" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central" class="mySvg__text">info</text>
      <text x="50" y="40" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central" class="mySvg__text">info</text>
</svg>
```

This way you could apply shared css styles but also select individual elements according to their global index.